# How to disable "Indexing Spring boot properties" notification from VS Code

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code

**Context** :
I have recently started using VS Code and trying to explore how easy/difficult it is to work with with a spring boot project with this editor.
I have installed the extension called "Spring boot extension pack".

**Problem**:
This is working well for the most part, except the fact that when i try to type in something on my properties file : application.properties, there is an annoying pop up that comes to the right bottom corner of the editor (Attached Screenshot) , which says "Indexing Spring Boot properties".
[image]

**Question**:
Is there a way to get rid of this notification ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to turn off the notifications, go through the following:

File > Preferences > Settings. Search up "Edit in Settings.json" in the settings bar and click "open the default settings JSON"
[image]

Press ctrl f for searching and type in "editor.parameterHints". You can disable notification pop-ups here by making it equal to "false". I am not sure if there is a way to turn off specific notifications however.